# Certificate bound to port not accepted

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, fiddler, bouncycastle

I made a tool that exposes a web-interface for the localhost. Now, i require this web-interface to register a https prefix for a page. For this i'm using BouncyCastle to generate a root certificate and a ssl certificate. This all works well (generating, signing and binding to port). IE displays the page by https **without** certificate warnings etc.

However, when a third party app tries to display the webpage, it fails (unable to load and displaying 'about:blank'). Because it is an embedded webbrowser i am not sure what the exact problem is. Thus, along other stuff, i tried to use fiddler to maybe determine the problem - only to find it DOES accept the certificate fiddler generates.

So what i have done is exporting the fiddler certificates and removed all custom certificates from the stores. Then, i imported the fiddler certificates on the exact same stores where my generated certificates are. I also made sure that the build up (all stuff you can inspect by viewing the certificate properties) are exactly the same. By using Windows MMC, clicking the certificates i can see NO difference, even the order is the same. Critical and such - all match. The only thing that is slightly different: the serial number from my certificates are shorter then the ones generated by fiddler.

So what i end up with are 4 certs (I deleted all the original from fiddler): 1 ssl and 1 root from fiddler and 1 ssl and 1 root from BouncyCastle. The roots are in trusted and the ssl in personal, both on localmachine. Now, when i use netsh to bind the fiddler cert to the port, it works. When i bind my own certificate to the port, it fails.

I have no idear why as all the properties look the same to me.

There is one thing though (again, i have no idea what is going wrong, so this might be irrelevant): on the SSL cert (so not the root one) the SKI points to nowhere (or, at least, i dont see where it points to), but this seems to be the case on the fiddler cert as well. Obviously for both certs the Authority key id point to their respective roots. The SKI on the SSL cert is set by

```
 certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(subjectKeyPair.Public));
```

BTW, i use a VM for testing wich is reset everytime, so i don't think i messed up the cert store somewhere along the way. The tool stays the same, the only thing that changes is the bound certificate, both are registered to 'localhost'

```
               IE        thirdparty browser
fiddler's     good           good
Own's         good           fail (without message)
```

Why can 2 seemingly identical certs have a different impact? Is there anything i'm missing in hidden properties or something? And, if so, what should i look for?

Comment: There is no such thing as binding a certificate to a port.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely useful comment and 2 downvotes!!! Ill keep this in mind! This makes perfect sense seeing that i tried my absolute best to A) explain my problem with the knowledge i posses(sed). B) Explain thoroughly what i have tried C) posted the solution that worked for me so that it might help others.

Next time i really should first figure out what the problem and solution are before i post a question (???)

Answer (score -1):

Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.... Minutes after this post i saw the flaw... It had not to do with the certificate at all, but the way it was bound to the port.... I used code from [Mike Bouck](https://mikebouck.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/http-server-api-net-wrapper/) to bind the certificate. This line was causing the problem...

```
 configSslParam.DefaultFlags = (uint)NativeMethods.HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_FLAG.HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_SSL_FLAG_NEGOTIATE_CLIENT_CERT;
```

Changing the flags to 0 made it work....

Wasted hours.... :(

Comment: This line of code does not bind a certificate to a port. Neither a certificate nor a port even appears in it. It configures the SSL context.